# Listen to promise as a stream

Tags: node.js, promise, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I have been reading about `Observables`. One thing I read about, is its ability to listen like a stream. I tried this using the following code.

```
const Rx = require('rxjs/Rx');
Promise = require('bluebird');

let i = 0;

function calculate() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setInterval(() => {
            console.log(++i);
            resolve(i);
        }, 5000);
    })
}


let source = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(calculate());

source.subscribe(
    next => {
        console.log(next, ' next ');
    },
    err => {
        console.error(err)
    },
    () => {
        console.log('done!');
    }
)
```

But it didn't work like a stream. So the output looks something like:

```
1
1 ' next '
done!
2
3
```

How do I continue listening to the promise? Is this one of the problem Observable really solve?

Comment: Promise can be resolved/rejected just once, so not sure what you would expect by resolving a promise multiple times. If you want to keep producing events in some intervals you can use `Rx.Observable.interval`.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak Could you please post an example in an answer

Comment: @SuhailGupta what is the use case do you want solve?

Comment: @mickaelw I have a function that periodically checks for any entry into the database. If there is, it needs to send an entry to another function, the one which will subscribe to it. Wanted to apply observable to this. (For Learning Sake)

Comment: An Rx observable is a function for a steam - a promise is a result of an operation - the "promise" analouge for something you can do multiple times is a promise returning function. You'd use `.defer` in Rx to interact with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Observable.fromPromise` is thought to convert a Promise to an Observable. As promises only can resolve once, this stream will always only output 1 item.

You can't enhance a promise functionality by wraping a stream over it. If the promise can only yield 1 value, only 1 value will get yielded in the resulting observable.

In your specific example, there's `Observable.interval(n)` which emits 1 item every `n` milliseconds. Else, for a more custom observable:

```
Rx.Observable.create(obs => {
    let i=0;
    setInterval(() => {
        obs.next(++i);
    }, 1000);
});
```

When you create an observable, you get an `Observer` instance that represents the observer that just subscribed to your stream. Notice that each new observer will create a new context (so in my example, each observer will have his `i` counter).

Comment: I do not think that answers his question. He said he wanted to periodically check the database thanks to his promise.

Comment: @mickaelw And I replied by saying that it's not posible to do with this approach because of the limitations of `Promise`, and that it should be easily refactored to `Rx.Observable.create`

Answer (score 0):

You can use switchMap and interval:

```
let i = 0;

function calculate() {
    return Promise.resolve(++i)
}
//I reduce to the strictly necessary for the answer, the promise's resolve. 
//It's possible to have more things 

let source = Rx.Observable
    .interval(1000)
    .switchMap(() => calculate())

source.subscribe(
    next => {
        console.log(next, ' next ');
    },
    err => {
        console.error(err)
    },
    () => {
        console.log('done!');
    }
)
```

You can see the documentation of switchMap and interval here:

- https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/interval.html
- https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html

And the demo: https://jsbin.com/nutukiyagi/1/edit?js,console

In this case, you never complete the stream, the console.log('done!') never appears in the console

Comment: @JLRishe you are right for the switchMap and is a mistake for the new before the promise, thanks! I update my answer

Answer (score 0):

From the docs for `Rx.Observable.fromPromise`:

> If the Promise resolves with a value, the output Observable emits that resolved value as a next, and then completes.

This describes exactly the behavior you're facing. You should use a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function%2A) or [`Rx.Observable.create`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-create) to solve this specific problem.